# Plotting a phase portrait with multiple colors with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, colors

I want to add something to make my phase portrait more understandable. Nevertheless, I can't find anything (I found this 
https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorspec.html
https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11611-linear-2d-plot-with-rainbow-color
https://se.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/linecolortype.html
) but it is not what I need.

I would really like to see the color of the line of the phase portrait changing depending of if it is at the beginning or at the end of the simulation.

I found this idea which seems great :

[image]

I don't understand at all what he has done (the code is I suppose written here: 
https://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/08/15/colors-for-your-multi-line-plots/ )
but It would be great if I can plot a one line function which color varies depending of the time. If moreover, like on the picture, I can have have a scale on the right: it would be awesome.

So for now, I have that :

```
data = readtable('test.txt');
figure('Name','Phase'  , 'units','normalized','outerposition',[(8/100) (0.3- 16/100) 0.5 0.7]);
hold on
   plot(data{:,2},data{:,3}, 'k.', 'LineWidth',1.5 );
   plot(data{:,4},data{:,5}, 'r.', 'LineWidth',1.5  );
xL = xlim;
yL = ylim;
line([0 0], yL);  %x-axis
line(xL, [0 0]);  %y-axis   
      title(['Phase portrait'])
      xlabel('f')
      ylabel('f '' ')
hold off
```

I read the values of the function in a .txt file, and then I plot the 2nd/3rd columns and 4/5th columns. The first column is the time evoluting.

Do you have any idea :)?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this, thanks to another user on stackoverflaw.

```
    data = readtable('4ressorspendule.txt');
n = numel(data.Var1);
c = size(data,2);

figure('Name','Phase'  , 'units','normalized','outerposition',[(8/100) (0.3 - 16/100) 0.5 0.7]);
for i=1:n
    hold on
    plot(data{i,2},data{i,3},'.','Color',[1 (1-i/n) 0] ,'MarkerSize',4);  
    plot(data{i,4},data{i,5},'.','Color',[0 (i/n) (1-i/n)],'MarkerSize',4);
end
xL = xlim;
yL = ylim;
line([0 0], yL);  %x-axis
line(xL, [0 0]);  %y-axis   
title(['Phase portrait'])
xlabel('f')
ylabel('f '' ')
hold off
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to go about this to be honest.
However it makes a bit easier if you let us know what your time data is.
Do you plot your time data on the x (or y) axis or is it a different additional data set. Should it be an additional data set then you can consider it like z-data, plotted on the Z-axis or/and as a color.
Below is an example of what you can do by making a 3D plot but displaying it in 2D, this allows you to add the colorbar without too many problems.

```
x=0:5;
y=0:5;
z=rand(1,6); %random data to simulate your time
xx=[x' x']; %this allows you to plot the data using surf in 3d
yy=[y' y']; %same as for xx
z1=zeros(size(xx)); % we don't need z-data so we're making it a matrix of zeros
zc=[z' z']; %input here your time data values, if x/y then you can just use those instead of z
hs=surf(xx,yy,z1,zc,'EdgeColor','interp') %// color binded to "z" values, choose interp for interpolated/gradual color changes, flat makes it sudden
colormap('hsv') %choose your colormap or make it yourself
view(2) %// view(0,90)
hcb=colorbar; %add a colorbar
```

Comment: hi! thanks for your answer. I tried to adapt my code but it is telling me Z is a matrix and not a vector. To answer your question, what you propose is, I think, a good way to solve my problem. The time would be the first collum in the .txt folder. Can it be done with your solution? I tried to write something like this : x=data{:,2}; y=data{:,3};

Comment: Yes but it is hard to say how to do it if I don't know what your data looks like.
It has to do probably with how you need to plot z1 and zc inside the surf function, because these just as xx and yy need to be matrices and NOT vectors, otherwise you can't use surf. ALSO xx, yy, z1 and zc all need to be same size (shape). It might be that you can enter your time data directly instead of having it to convert to a matrix (if it's already a matrix).

Comment: So what shape does your data have?